# NetLogo histogram data

Tags: netlogo

I tried posting this to the NetLogo user group on Yahoo but wasn't successful in getting the post accepted. So I'm trying here.

NetLogo can plot histograms. Is there any way to get access to the histogram data, i.e., the data generated for the histogram plot?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy Holidays, Russ!

I don't think it's possible to get the values. Though if you wanted to implement your own histogram for data, you could use something like:

```
to-report calc-histogram [ aList numBars aMaxValue ]
  let minValue min aList
  let interval (aMaxValue - minValue) / numBars
  let hist []
  foreach n-values numBars [?] [
   let lowerBound minValue + (? * interval)
   let upperBound lowerBound + interval
   let x (lowerBound + upperBound) /  2
   let y length filter [? >= lowerBound and ? < upperBound] aList
   set hist lput (list x y ) hist
  ]
  report hist 
end
```

example usage:

```
observer> calc-histogram [0 1 18 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 9 10 7 15 7 17 18 19 ] 5 20
observer: [[2 4] [6 8] [10 2] [14 1] [18 4]]
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, Happy Holidays to you too! Didn't know (or at least didn't remember) that you were a NetLogo hacker. I did it myself after discovering that NetLogo now has array and (hash-)table extensions built in. With those it was so simple there was no need to bother with anything else. Thanks.